# How do i install AD FS management tools on windows 10 pro to remotely manage my AD FS server

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2016, adfs

As the title says: i have an AD FS server installed on windows server 2016.
The server is installed in basic form, so console only, no gui.

I am working from a windows 10 pro machine. how do i get AD FS remote management tools? or can this role only be managed locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of February 2017, there is no remote UI for AD FS per this User Voice issue. Normally, it would be included in something like [RSAT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520).

[ADFS Management Console missing from RSAT](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/295065-security-and-assurance/suggestions/17952562-adfs-management-console-missing-from-rsat)

The current recommendation is to use Powershell via WinRM to manage remote AD FS instances.

Comment: Ugh. It's sooo much faster and easier to set up or adjust a relying party via the mmc snapin. It's something that happens infrequently, so it's not like there's a big advantage to being able to script it, and this is also the kind of server where it'd be really nice to be able to disable remote desktop access.