# ADFS management console or RSAT for Windows 10?

Tags: adfs

I know this question has been asked two years ago ([How do i install AD FS management tools on windows 10 pro to remotely manage my AD FS server](https://serverfault.com/questions/847796)), has there been any change?  It would be great to be able to manage ADFS sitting on a headless core Windows server from a workstation.

Installing the role was easy enough, but configuring a passing SAML consumer claim from powershell feels like a *lot* of trial and error.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i install AD FS management tools on windows 10 pro to remotely manage my AD FS server](https://serverfault.com/questions/847796/how-do-i-install-ad-fs-management-tools-on-windows-10-pro-to-remotely-manage-my)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not very helpful to ask for follow-up on an old question by asking a new question.

Comment: It might not exactly be a _new_ question but I was thinking it might be timely (lol).  After all, the answer might have changed in the interim...it has been a couple of years since the original asking and response.

Though I am glad to edit or retract the question.  For anyone curious, not only are the tools not available to Windows 10, ADFS installed on a core server (win2k19) can not be managed from another server's management tools either.  It seems the choice is powershell on the core server or simply install the role on a server with the gui to avoid a lot of trial and error.